# Failed to pull image from Docker local insecure registry: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: docker, kubernetes, https, docker-registry

when I try to deploy application in Kubernetes using images in my private Docker registry on same server (master node), I receive following error:

> Failed to pull image
>   "0.0.0.0:5000/continuous-delivery-tutorial:5ec98331a69ec5e6f818583d4506d361ff4de89b-2020-02-12-14-37-03":
>   rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://0.0.0.0:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS
>   client

When I print `docker system info` I can see there is my registry as insecure registry:

[image]

I run my registry by following command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v $PWD/docker_reg_certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key registry:2
```

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add your hostname to the list of allowed insecure registries in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, for example:

```json
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["your-computer-hostname:5000"]
}
```

(this file is supposed to contain 1 json object, so if it's not empty then add `insecure-registries` property to the existing object instead of creating a new one. Also remember to restart your docker daemon afterwards)

also, you should not use `0.0.0.0` as it is not a real address. use your hostname instead when specifying image, like `your-computer-hostname:5000/continuous-delivery-tutorial:5ec98331a69ec5e6f818583d4506d361ff4de89b-2020-02-12-14-37-03`

Comment: Thank you, it works now. However, I found that it was not working for obvious reason: it was calling registry on different node. For single node cluster it works

Comment: after changing the daemon.json file do not forget to restart docker daemon: "sudo service docker restart"

Comment: Thanks a lot; although at last I realized that I should not create another json block, but add to the previous existent one. Thus the suggestion of edit.

Comment: @WesternGun json does not allow comments. I've reverted the code and added a note below to not confuse ppl  ;-)

Comment: @UriLoya I've added a note about to the answer. Thx!

Comment: For anyone using buildx, note that you have to `docker buildx rm` and then `docker buildx create` after making these changes on your host. Otherwise, the buildx container will continue to hold on to the old (non-existent) list of insecure registries. Simply restarting Docker on your host machine doesn't cause the buildx container to pull in the newer daemon config.